# How to recalculate cellFilter values when model changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I have data displayed in a ui-grid in an Angular application and one of the fields is a date/time. This is calculated by a cell filter, based on a timezone selected in the main menu bar of the application which uses a value in the rootScope as its model.

The filter is currently defined like this (on the controller):

```
.filter('selectedTimeZoneFilter', function() {
  return function(value, timeZone) {
    return moment(value).tz(timeZone.value).format('DD/MM/YY HH:mm');
  };
})
```

.. and the value is passed in via a cellFilter definition like this:

```
cellFilter: 'selectedTimeZoneFilter:grid.appScope.timeZone'
```

..finally, the value to be passed is set in the controller from the root scope:

```
var vm = this;
vm.timeZone = $rootScope.timezone;
```

This is fine for the initial display of the values - when the grid is first generated it uses the currently selected timezone value to display the dates/times. However, this doesn't seem to give Angular enough information to know that the values should be recalculated when the timezone changes (via a select box which uses $rootScope.timezone as its model).

Is there an easy way to tell Angular that the cell contents are dependent on the timezone selection and need to be recalculated when it changes, or do I need to do some sort of manual regeneration with something like an ng-change tag?

Comment: Can you please add a plunker for this

Answer (score 0):

As the row data is not changing on timezone change, it doesn't recalculate. So, after change of timeZone dropdown, try calling

```
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
```

This should recalculate all values